# Run downloaded nodejs package

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed a nodejs package (module?) using

```
sudo npm install -g ng-annotate
```

*How can I start it?*

I've tried

```
npm run ng-annotate test
```

and it indeed runs some tests and they all pass. Nice, but replacing `test` by anything else produces no output at all and the return code is zero. For example,

```
npm run ng-annotate npn is a crap!
```

does nothing at all. I've also tried `nodejs whatever`, etc. What I want should look like

```
npm run ng-annotate run --add - < infile.js > outfile.js
```

I must confess I haven't read *all* the help available, but it's the very first tools which ignores all invalid inputs and keeps secret how to run it. I don't want to learn nodejs *now*; all I need is to run the script.

Comment: try `ng-annotate --add - < infile.js > outfile.js`

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny `ng-annotate: command not found`. Actually, I've read somewhere that `install -g` works like this, but it doesn't.

Comment: `npm` installs global packages into the same directory `node` is installed, which should be in your `$PATH` already (see [npm-folders(5) docs](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v1.4.10/doc/files/npm-folders.md#prefix-configuration)).

Comment: Obviously, your problem is environmental, though I'm not sure what it is. Are you sure that you installed `node` and `npm` correctly?

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I'm not sure what I'd have to do to install it incorrectly. Any idea? But your comments helped me to solve it (hacky solution, but it's good enough for now). Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments,

```
ng-annotate run --add - < infile.js > outfile.js
```

should do. There's a link

```
/bin/ls -l /usr/bin/ng-annotate
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 2014-08-12 11:53 /usr/bin/ng-annotate -> ../lib/node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/ng-annotate
```

leading to an inaccessible file

```
sudo /bin/ls -l /usr/lib/node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/ng-annotate
-rwx------ 1 nobody maaartin 49 2014-08-09 00:43 /usr/lib/node_modules/ng-annotate/build/es5/ng-annotate
```

I reinstalled `npm` and it did not help. Fixing the permissions manually did.

Comment: I think this problem appeared because you installed `npm` as superuser. You may want to [install node and npm without having to sudo](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) instead.

Comment: ng-annotate author here. After installing ng-annotate via `npm install -g ng-annotate` you can run it as simply as `ng-annotate -a infile.js > outfile.js`.

Comment: @olov Not on my computer... there's something wrong with the permissions I get after installing. However, I fixed them manually and now it runs as described. The tool is great!